# Add background to first row and first column of Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I am trying to figure out how to add a background color to both the first row and all of the cells in the first column in my RadGrid.

Comment: just a simple question, but are you aware that the Telerik site has tons of working tutorials for this.. check their web site also please show that you have thus far and what you have tried on your own..

Comment: You are correct. I probably shouldn't of posted it on here. I normally google like crazy for something like this but just wasn't able to find a solution for a while. I just figured it out. sorry

Answer (score 1):

To add a background color to any specific column simply set the ItemStyle-BackColor property of the column:

```
ItemStyle-BackColor="LightGrey"
```

To add a background color to the first row you can do this in the grid's PreRender event:

```
protected void grid_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (grid.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        //Format first row of grid
        grid.Items[0].BackColor = Color.LightGray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use cell formatting event.

```
void radGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.CellFormattingEventArgs e)     
{     
    if (e.CellElement.ColumnInfo is GridViewDataColumn)     
    {     
        if (((GridViewDataColumn)e.CellElement.ColumnInfo).FieldName == "City")     
        {     
            e.CellElement.DrawFill = true;     
            e.CellElement.NumberOfColors = 1;     
            e.CellElement.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Beige;     
        }     
    }     
}
```